# navigate to somewhere else on page refresh

Tags: javascript, navigation

I have some web application at say www.somewebsite.com, when user refreshes the page, I want it to navigate to say www.google.com or anything else.

What I tried was attach event

```
window.onunload = function(){...}
```

and

```
window.beforeunload = function(){...}
```

I tried

```
window.location = "http://google.com"
```

for some reason it is not working.

Anybody has idea how to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I guess it's for security issues

Comment: That would be the most annoying thing if it worked.

Comment: I want to make it work, any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It CANNOT be done. The browser does not allow change of window url inside onunload or onbeforeunload. So, anybody else who is trying to do the same dont waste your time.